# How to create dynamic partial view in ASP.Net MVC footer section

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i am working on one application where i need to display last updated date and time of data from database to layout view footer section so that it will display on all the pages of application

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. create a Base View Model and make your layout strongly typed for this all your model should be inherited from BaseVM and in every Action you will have to populate the properties of BaseVM along with the model related to the Action method.
2. Create an Action Filter, which will I recommend.
   for details check this
   https://www.sharpencode.com/article/MVC/filters-in-asp-net-mvc/actionfilter